# If $y=x\log\left(\frac{x}{a+bx}\right)$, then prove that $x^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $y=x\log\left(\dfrac{x}{a+bx}\right)$, then prove that $x^3\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left(x\dfrac{dy}{dx}-y\right)$.

**My attempt:**

By differentiating, I get

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=\frac{a}{a+bx}$$

On differentiating again, I got

$$x^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-abx^2}{(a+bx)^2}$$

Clearly, I somehow cannot equalise the LHS and RHS of the equation. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$y=x \log \left(\frac{x}{a+b x}\right)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a}{a+b x}+\log \left(\frac{x}{a+b x}\right)$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{a^2}{x (a+b x)^2}$$
$$x^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{a^2 x^2}{ (a+b x)^2}$$
$$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}-y=\frac{a x}{a+b x}$$ So it seems that there is a typo somewhere since we find that
$$x^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left(x\dfrac{dy}{dx}-y\right)^\color{red}{\Large2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, sir. Also, many thanks for pointing out the mistake in the question.

Comment: @AakhiChatterjee. You are welcome ! Check your derivatives again (if I may suggest). Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I seem to have made mistakes at both places.